# UIButton Background Colour Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, background-color, ibdesignable

I have created a series of 'translucent' UI elements using `@IBDesignable` where I set the background colour to white with a low, partial alpha.

This works for `UIView` but for `UIButton` the background stays clear and the text colour, while correctly appears as white at runtime, shows as the default blue in Xcode (IB).

What am I doing wrong here? If it works for `UIView` I do not understand why the same code does not work for `UIButton`.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class TranslucentButton: UIButton {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.1)
        setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        layer.cornerRadius = 4
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}

@IBDesignable
class TransulucentUIView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.1)

        layer.cornerRadius = 4
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a higher alpha value. `0.1` is nearly invisible.

Comment: He has the same alpha on the UIView and he sees that. Problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I am getting color even though alpha is light.                         backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 1/255, blue: 1/255, alpha: 0.1)